# Ruby on Rails - Problem ActiveRecord, Migrations and two columns to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rails-migrations

Okay so what I have is a table that keeps track of history on a "person", this logs the person(User), the handler(User), the status before(JobApplicationStatus), the status after(JobApplicationStatus).

Now in my head this translates down to a table of such:

```
**JobApplicationHistory**
id (int)
status_before_id (int)
status_after_id (int)
user_id (int)
handler_id (int)
```

I tried to make a migation, that sorta worked, but it's not working right.

As I would like to use something like:

```
user = User.find(1)
handler = User.find(1)
status_before = JobApplicationStatus.find(1)
status_after = JobApplicationStatus.find(2)

history = JobApplicationHistory.new()
history.user = user
history.handler = handler
history.status_before = status_before
history.status_after = status_after
history.save
```

### Here is my migration

`class CreateUserApplicationHistories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :user_application_histories do |t|
      t.integer :user_id # goes to User
      t.references :job # goes to Job
      t.integer :handler_id # goes to User
      t.integer :status_from_id # goes to JobApplicationStatus
      t.integer :status_to_id # goes to JobApplicationStatus
      t.timestamps
    end`

```
add_index("user_application_histories", "job_id")
add_index("user_application_histories", "handler_id")
add_index("user_application_histories", "user_id")
add_index("user_application_histories", "status_from_id")
add_index("user_application_histories", "status_to_id")
```

end

def self.down
    drop_table :user_application_histories
  end
end

### And my model, which i think makes it fail

`class UserApplicationHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status_from_id, :class_name => "JobApplicationStatus"
    belongs_to :status_to_id, :class_name => "JobApplicationStatus"
  belongs_to :user_id, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :handler_id, :class_name => "User"
end`

Comment: What is the error/failure that you are seeing?

Comment: It's not assigning anything, the status_before and the others remains null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right, your model should look like this for user and handler:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :handler, :class_name => "User"
```

To help you with JobApplicationStatus I would need to know how this table looks like

Comment: The foreign_key is implicit. You should only use that option if it's not `[association_name]_id`.

Comment: @Ryan, your right, i've edited my answer to make it better ;)